# Extracting string with an optional ending pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract a substring that may either appear between two substrings or in the end of the original string. The starting delimiter is `ab` and the ending delimiter may be `cd` or the end of the original string.

Examples:

```
c = 'ab123:random text1 cd4576:text2'
d = 'cd123:text2 ab75589:text1'
e = 'ab35:rand text2 cd765:text1'
```

Desired answer:

```
c = 'random text1'
d = 'text1'
e = 'rand text2'
```

I am able to match the starting substring with `re.findall('ab\d+:(.*)', i)`. But when I try to add the ending pattern, I cannot find the desired answer:

```
re.findall('ab\d+:(.*)', i)
>>> ['random text1 cd4576: text2'], [' text1'], ['rand text2 cd765: text1']

re.findall('^ab\d+:(.*)cd\d+:', i)
>>>['random text1 '], [], ['rand text2 ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall(r'\bab\d+:(.*?)(?:\s*\bcd|$)', i)` instead.

Comment: It worked with the following modification: `re.findall(r'\bab\d+:((.|\n)*?)(?:\s*\bcd\d+|$)'`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using the or  "|" with group like this:

```
re.findall('ab[^:]+:[ \t]*(.+)[ \t]*(cd[^:]+|$):', i)
```

you also neet to exclude the "cd" inside content itself (in this pattern, a space serve as separator but imagine variant on string like `'ab123:random text1 de23:acdc cd4576:text2'`